# Add multiple jlabel on jpanel and on same line using box layout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

Want to add two jlabel with some space on same line to jpanel, japnel layout is set to box layout,due to some constraints i can't change layout to another and property of box layout from Y_AXIS to LINE_AXIS, so please provide me with some solution, so i can put jlabel on same line..

[image]

```
contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

So please let me know the solution for the same mentioned above.

Comment: Why can't you change the axis? And why these constraints? Doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you believe you can't change the layout because you're dealing with the content pane of a JFrame and you don't want to change the rest of the window.

If that's the case, you can use nested layouts by adding the two JLabels to a separate JPanel (let's call it labelPanel) and adding that to the content pane. It would look something like this:

```
JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
labelPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labelPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
labelPanel.add(leftLabel);
labelPanel.add(Box.createGlue()); //creates space between the JLabels
labelPanel.add(rightLabel);

contentPane.add(labelPanel);
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your labels in a `JPanel` with a `Border` layout.  Add one to the West panel and another to the East panel.  Set the alignment of the `JLabels` as needed.  Then add the `JPanel` to your box layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out: `JPanel` with `GridLayout`, and `JLabel`s left and right aligned. The frame is a Box still uses a box. What should interest you is the `JPanel panel` code. That's where I'm adding the labels. All you have to do is nest components and layouts

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class TwoLabels extends JFrame{

    public TwoLabels(){
        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Hello");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("World");
        label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEADING);
        label2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.TRAILING);
        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(label2);

        box.add(new JPanel(){
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                return new Dimension(300, 300);
            }
        });
        box.add(panel);

        add(box);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TwoLabels();

    }
}
```